# Gitk --all not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: git, 15.10

Yesterday I upgraded my machine from Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10. Now `gitk` does not work with the option `--all`. Whenever I try to use it the system crashes and the machine reboots.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the `nouveau` driver of the video card. I changed to the proprietary Nvidia driver and now the problem seems to be gone